# Tearing graphics in SCNView

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

[image: SCNView Tearing]

Hi, I have a SCNView with some nodes, when rotating I get some strange tearing, the nodes on top have a higher rendering order, changing this seems to have no effect.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the white lines?

It's like it's fighting for position??

Comment: looks like regular z-fighting (look it up), the white plane and blue/purple areas are probably on the same plane or very close to each other. Not sure about scenekit but usually you can improve tings by choosing a larger z buffer (ie 24 bit instead of 8). But it's never going to go away completely for flat, overlapping surfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as said above, it looks like you're experiencing z-fighting because your colored objects and white object lie in a same plane.

You can avoir this

1. By slightly offsetting your geometries, but this trick does not work in every situation (the user might notice the gap depending on the point of view)
2. by changing the `renderingOrder` of your nodes but don't forget to tweak the `writesToDepthBuffer` and `readsFromDepthBuffer` properties of your materials

Answer (score 2):

When use NO.2 solution mnuages introduced:

```
node.renderingOrder = 100;//Max value to ensure your node render at latest.
//disable deep buffer for rendering
node.firstMaterial.writesToDepthBuffer = NO;
node.firstMaterial.readsFromDepthBuffer = NO;
```

This is only work for node's geometry locate top hierarchy otherwise will lead to a weird perspective scenario.